# How can I add a value to a specific key to a YAML file in Python?

Tags: python, yaml, discord.py

Recently I would like to work with YAML file even more with my discord.py bot. So I am currently thinking how do I add a value to a specific key in a YAML file. This is my current YAML file:

```
connected_guilds:
    - 1st_guild_id
```

And whenever it connects to another guild, it should appears like so:

```
connected_guilds:
    - 1st_guild_id
    - 2nd_guild_id
```

etc.

Here is my current code:

```
        with open('guilds.yaml', 'r+') as guild_add:
            yaml.dump({'connected_guilds'.replace("'", ""): [guild_id]}, guild_add, indent=4)
```

So basically I think if I should have an if-clause checking if the key already exists and if so, add it below but I'm still confused while implementing that.

I'd be grateful if someone can help!

Comment: What problem do you have with it? SO is a site to help you with your problems, but please don't just come here and expect us to write code for you without trying anything on your own.

Comment: please, I have tried to write but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening, but not reading the file. You create a new list instead of appending to the existing list.

Here's how to do it:

```py
with open('guilds.yaml', 'r+') as f:
  # load the content
  content = yaml.safe_load(f)
  # append the new id to the existing list
  content["connected_guilds"].append(guild_id)
  # reset the position in the file (it's at the end since we read the file)
  f.seek(0)
  # write the updated YAML to the file
  yaml.dump(content, f)
  # throw away any (old) content of the file after the current position,
  # which is at the end of the YAML we just wrote.
  # since we added more content, it's unlikely that there is more content here,
  # but not impossible!
  f.truncate()
```

Comment: So does the same applies to value removal?

Comment: Yes, it applies to all normal list operations. For anything you do, just do it on the loaded Python objects with normal dict/list operations.